# How can I stop PHPStorm tooltips from blocking the typing view?

Tags: phpstorm, tooltip

This is getting to be rather annoying and has only really started happening recently (or I've only started noticing it recently) but the the documentation tooltip in PHPStorm has been coming in the way of me typing and it has blocked my view more than once.

I wanted to ask this before but I could never capture the screen properly it would always disappear, however I got a screenshot now!

**Example**

[image]

As you can see it is completely blocking the view of where I am typing which makes it extremely difficult to know what I'm typing.

So,

**How can I stop the tooltip from blocking the typing view?**

Answer (score 0):

Verify the `Autopopup documentation in ms:` flag is enabled in `File | Settings | Editor | General | Code Completion`.